# How to add multiple markers with Instagram pictures on google maps

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

So I'm pretty much trying to get multiple markers on google maps. Every marker contains an Instagram image from a certain user. At the moment I can show a marker of only 1 Instagram image. I know that I need to make an array and that I should loop that array, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that at the moment. Here are some parts of my code so far:

```
foreach($phplijst->data as $data){

            $lat = [$data->location->latitude];
            $lng = [$data->location->longitude];


            echo "['".$data->images->low_resolution->url."',".$data->location->latitude.",".$data->location->longitude."]";

    }

<script>

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo "".$lat.",".$lng.""; ?>);
```

These are just some parts of my code but you should know what I've done here. I've got the location of multiple images, but I don't know how to loop them. At the moment I'm only getting a marker of the first image. Does anyone know how to loop the images + location?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to this in my Maps; is this any help to you:

I declared a varible called map:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Then did a loop:

```
for (var obj in data) {

    var pointer = data[obj];

    pointer.image = "red_icon.png";

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(pointer.Latitude, pointer.Longitude);

    pointer.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: pointer.Title,
        icon: "../../Content/images/" + pointer.image,
        custom: { id : pointer.ObjectiveId }

    });
}
```